# Calling C function fgetc from NASM, it always returns a -1

Tags: assembly, x86, std, nasm, calling-convention

Using NASM, I'm trying to open a text file and print each character of the text file. The problem is, `fgetc` is continuously returning a `-1`.

```
    extern  printf
    extern  fopen
    extern  fgetc
    extern  fclose

SECTION .data           ; Data section, initialized variables

    p1_fmt:   db   0xA, "blah", 0xA, 0xA, 0
    p2_fmt:   db   0xA, "Opening: stuff.txt", 0xA, 0xA, 0
    p3_fmt:   db   0xA, "Closing.", 0xA, 0xA, 0
    result_fmt:   db   0xA, "search results: a=%d, e=%d, i=%d, o=%d, u=%d", 0
    p5_fmt:   db   0xA, "debug", 0
    p6_fmt:   db   0xA, "character: %d", 0xA, 0
    file_name:  db  "stuff.txt", 0
    file_mode:  db  "r", 0

SECTION .bss            ; Data section, uninitialized variables

    num_a   resd 0
    num_e   resd 0
    num_i   resd 0
    num_o   resd 0
    num_u   resd 0


SECTION .text           ; Code section.

    global main         ; the standard gcc entry point

main:               ; the program label for the entry point
    push    p1_fmt
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    push    p2_fmt
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    ;push    file_mode
    ;push    file_name

    mov     DWORD [esp], file_name
    mov     DWORD [esp + 4], file_mode
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 8

    push   eax ; push file pointer on stack.

    character:
        call    fgetc ; an int is in eax now
        mov     ebx, eax ; ebx holds this int too

        ; this continuously print a -1...
        push    ebx
        push    p6_fmt
        call    printf
        add     esp, 8

        cmp ebx, 0
        je no_characters_left

        ; need to loop thru all the characters.
        cmp     ebx, 97
        je vowel_a

        cmp     ebx, 101
        je vowel_e

        cmp     ebx, 105
        je vowel_i

        cmp     ebx, 111
        je vowel_o

        cmp     ebx, 117
        je vowel_u
        jne character

        vowel_a:
            mov eax, num_a
            inc eax
            mov [num_a], eax
            jmp character
        vowel_e:
            mov eax, num_e
            inc eax
            mov [num_e], eax
            jmp character
        vowel_i:
            mov eax, num_i
            inc eax
            mov [num_i], eax
            jmp character
        vowel_o:
            mov eax, num_o
            inc eax
            mov [num_o], eax
            jmp character
        vowel_u:
            mov eax, num_u
            inc eax
            mov [num_u], eax
            jmp character

    no_characters_left:
        call fclose
        add esp, 4 ; remove file pointer off the stack

        push    p5_fmt
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4

    mov     eax, 0      ; normal, no error, return value
    ret                 ; return
```

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that the calling convention on your system is `cdecl` and did you also remember to `sub esp, 8` before putting the arguments on stack?

Comment: 1. yes. i'm using ubuntu 32-bit. 2. yes, here is the full code: http://hastebin.com/ijuyuvipay.avrasm

Comment: Are you compiling it as 32 bit or 64 bit? Those instructions are perfectly valid for a 64 bit system but you won't be generating the correct ones for the x86-64 calling convention.

Comment: i am compiling it as 32-bit i believe:

`nasm -f elf test.asm`

`gcc test.o -masm=intel -o test`

Comment: can you show me what i should change so it can be valid for 32-bit?

Comment: specify `-f elf32` instead of just `elf` - also, assuming you're linking it using gcc, make sure you pass `-m32` to that.

Comment: Dumb question, but is it possible that the text went by so fast that you missed the fact that it didn't return -1 at the beginning of the output. `-1` would be `EOF`.

Comment: `cmp ebx, 0` looks suspect for checking if there are characters left. ASCII 0 (nul) is still a valid character. `libc` usually returns -1 (on Linux) from `fgetc` when EOF is encountered.

Comment: Something else that is odd is that you do this: `mov DWORD [esp], file_name` and `mov DWORD [esp + 4], file_mode` You put these on the stack clobbering the return address for the function. Not sure why you didn't do `push file_mode` followed by `push file_name` instead (especially since you `add esp, 8` after you call `fopen`). Likely this will cause some form of hang or segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. One isn't related to `fgetc`. You do an *fopen* call like this:

```
    mov     DWORD [esp], file_name
    mov     DWORD [esp + 4], file_mode
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 8
```

The two *MOV* instructions destroyed the return address for the calling function. This will likely result in a segfault when you return from function `main` . I believe it should look like this:

```
    push    file_mode
    push    file_name
    call    fopen
    add     esp, 8
```

`fgetc` returns *EOF* (on Linux *EOF* usually maps to -1). Instead you are checking for the ASCII value 0 (nul) to detect the end of the stream. ASCII 0(nul) is a valid character to read from a stream. You should change this check:

```
    cmp ebx, 0
    je no_characters_left
```

to:

```
    cmp ebx, -1
    je no_characters_left
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've made the appropriate changes. So, I just woke up and discovered that there wasn't any text in the textfile... I have no idea how this went by my head. :(. Thank you both Olipro and Michael for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Perhaps when I changed the file mode to `w+` it wiped the text file.

Comment: Something erased it. Glad you discovered it was empty ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so based on the comments I think this will be our likely answer:

1. use `-f elf32` when compiling with nasm
2. use `-m32` when linking with GCC.

Comment: damn, i am now doing

`nasm -f elf32 test.asm`

`gcc -m32 test.o -masm=intel -o test`

`./test`

but it is still printing -1 continuously.

Comment: OK, so change the file mode from `r` to `w+` and see if it's simply failing because the file doesn't actually exist.

Comment: didn't work. i have also changed the filename in the code to something obscure, and the program does crash then. so it knows that it exists.